# Handling character with world object collision in libgdx and bullet

Tags: libgdx, 3d, bullet-physics

I am using libgdx and bullet for my 3d mmo project. I have been able to detect collisions using a collision world with collision objects. This was working fine for things like detecting players hitting each other but I was having problems handling players hitting walls or other world objects.

After some searching I came across rigid bodies and the dynamics world. This seemed like it would solve my issue but once I got my objects converted over to rigid bodies my collision handler is no longer detecting collisions and the player is still going through walls.

I would like to not have to handle the low level details of players not going through walls but I would still like to be able to manually handle collisions of collision objects for things like spells or weapons. What is the best way to go about this? I am also seeing different bullet objects like static, kinematic, dynamic, but I am not sure which is best for my situation. I also am thinking that part of my problem may be that I am translating my character every update instead of updating its velocity.

What is the best setup for accomplishing this?

Comment: hey, have you solved this?

Comment: @lxknvlk I had to resort to handling collisions manually, looking at the collision penetration and angle in order to resolve the collision. I could look and post some of my code if you need.